# How hard or easy those Haworthias are to cultivate?

Tags: succulents, rot, climate

Those Haworthias are sold in the range of $40 to $50 equivalent, while standard ones are marketed in the range of $3 to $5, depending on size. This is from a local grower in my country, not an online purchase, but still too expensive. Money issues left aside, I am reluctant to buy at such high prices (even if the quality justifies that) following my bitter experience with few of the potting mixes which did not meet my expectations. My cultivation method is growing them outside, in the open. Shade, if needed, is provided. There is no frost and they can be left outside. My climate is a warm Mediterranean: No winter frost, but there are heat waves in the summer and erratic but high rainfalls in winter.

So, should I buy them, or would they have any special needs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Haworthia can be very difficult to grow.  Many want a growing medium that is almost 100% gritty (inorganic) matter with little to no organic (water holding) matter.  Others can be easier to grow.  They ones that use to be called Haworthia that are not called Haworthiopsis are the easiest of the Haworthia to grow.  Those are also the most common.  They can handle full sun and be over-watered occasionally.

Some of the ones in the picture are extremely challenging.  They want bright indirect light and well drained soil.  They will not tolerate cool wet winters.  Succulents in general are good at handling cool, even occasional cold, but cool and wet they can not tolerate.  The roots will rot.  Cool and dry is much better.

That does not mean you can not enjoy succulents outside in winter.  Just put them under the eaves of the house.  This will protect them from the wet winters.  I would stick with the Haworthiopsis and Tulistia genus, both until recently included in with Haworthia.  These type can tolerate full sun to part shade.  The Haworthia in the picture are grow by rock where they are shaded from the full sun.  They do like it bright indirect light, not deep shade.

Comment: Thanks, I have lately designated a sheltered place for my Haworthias. All those that do not take the higher rainfall in winter will go there, including those in the picture above (Anyway, most death cases happen in the summer, if any). The

Comment: I hope you have great success.  (I'm an all season killer)